# Fields Added Via Javascript not posting Data into $POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a form which can be dynamically changed using the buttons included. These buttons allow for more input fields to be added/removed. The issue is that the input fields created are not posting any data/ Values in those fields not being added to the $POST array on the submit of the form.

The main functions below resposible for adding and removing rows is RemoveRows() and addRows()

What should happen is that on submit all values in the form should be "posted" then I can access all of those fields via $_POST["nameOfField"].

The way I have currently approached this is to create an input fields with the relevant id's and names then append that field to where the "hard coded" fields exists.

From my initial debugging none of the fields that have been added via javascript are in $Post which I have checked via var_dump($_REQUEST);

I have also seen that the nodes that are added are not elements of the form tag even though the nodes are added between the opening  and closing  tag. This can be seen in the doBeforeSubmit() Function where we can see all elements that are children of the  and this never changes as rows are added/removed.

```js
function showPlatforms() {
  let nacellesOptions = ["Option1", "option2", "Option3"];
  let milOptions = ["Option1", "option2", "Option3"]
  let highOptions = ["Option1", "option2", "Option3"]
  let entry = document.getElementById("vs")
  let platfom = document.getElementById("platform")

  if (platform.hasChildNodes()) {
    var lastChild = platfom.lastElementChild
    while (lastChild) {
      platfom.removeChild(lastChild)
      lastChild = platform.lastElementChild
    }
  }

  if (entry.value == "Nacelles") {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = nacellesOptions[i]
      option.innerHTML = nacellesOptions[i]
      platform.appendChild(option)
    }
  } else if (entry.value == "Military") {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = milOptions[i]
      option.innerHTML = milOptions[i]
      platform.appendChild(option)
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = highOptions[i]
      option.innerHTML = highOptions[i]
      platform.appendChild(option)
    }
  }


}

function formOptions() {
  let entry = document.getElementById("type")
  if (entry.value == "Engineering MAM") {
    document.getElementById("WBS").disabled = false
    document.getElementById("Desc").disabled = false
    document.getElementById("ProName").disabled = false
  } else {
    document.getElementById("WBS").disabled = true
    document.getElementById("Desc").disabled = true
    document.getElementById("ProName").disabled = true
  }

}

function formoptions2() {
  let entry2 = document.getElementById("organisation")
  if (entry2.value == "Aftermarket") {
    document.getElementById("COT").disabled = false
    document.getElementById("COC").disabled = false
  } else {
    document.getElementById("COT").disabled = true
    document.getElementById("COC").disabled = true

  }

}

count = document.getElementById("partNum").childElementCount

function addRows() {
  rowNames = ["partNum", "partDesc", "leadTime", "quantity", "dateReq", "unitCost", "unitExtention", "unitSaleValue", "estSalesValue"]
  rowNames.forEach(addRow, count)
  count = document.getElementById("partNum").childElementCount
  //doBeforeSubmit() 
}

function doBeforeSubmit() {
  var es = document.getElementById("form").elements;
  var l = es.length;

  var msgs = [];

  for (var idx = 0; idx < l; idx++) {
    var e = es[idx];
    msgs.push('name=' + e.name + ', type=' + e.type + ', value=' + e.value);
  }

  alert(msgs.join('\n'));
  return false;
}

function addRow(id) {
  let col = document.getElementById(id)
  var box = document.createElement("INPUT")
  box.setAttribute("type", "text")
  box.setAttribute("id", id + count)
  box.setAttribute("name", id + count)
  box.setAttribute("class", "form-control")
  col.appendChild(box)
}

function RemoveRows() {
  rowNames = ["partNum", "partDesc", "leadTime", "quantity", "dateReq", "unitCost", "unitExtention", "unitSaleValue", "estSalesValue"]
  rowNames.forEach(removeBoxes)
  count = document.getElementById("partNum").childElementCount
}

function removeBoxes(item) {
  let box = document.getElementById(item)
  let last = box.lastChild
  box.removeChild(last)
}

function checkData() {
  // if all stuff is correct do this:
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false

  // else dont activate the submit button.
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form" action="SubmitMAM.php">
  <div class="row" id="productRow" style="width:95%; margin:auto">

    <div id="partNo" class="col-2">
      <h3>Part Number:</h3>


    </div>

    <div class="col-2">
      <h3>Part Description:</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <h3>Lead Time:</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <h3>Quantity:</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <h3>Date Required:</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <h3>Unit Cost:</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="col-2">
      <h3>Unit Cost Extension:</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <h3>Unit Sale Value:</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <h3>Est Sales Value:</h3>
    </div>


  </div>


  <div class="row" id="productRow" style="width:95%; margin:auto">

    <div id="partNum" class="col-2">
      <input type="text" id="partNum0" class="form-control" name="partNum0">
    </div>

    <div id="partDesc" class="col-2">
      <input type="text" id="partDesc0" class="form-control" name="partDesc0">

    </div>

    <div id="leadTime" class="col-1">
      <input type="text" id="leadTime0" class="form-control" name="leadTime0">

    </div>

    <div id="quantity" class="col-1">
      <input type="text" id="quanitity0" class="form-control" name="quantity0">

    </div>

    <div id="dateReq" class="col-1">
      <input type="text" id="dateReq0" class="form-control" name="dateReq0">

    </div>

    <div id="unitCost" class="col-1">
      <input type="text" id="unitCost0" class="form-control" name="unitCost0">

    </div>

    <div id="unitExtention" class="col-2">
      <input type="text" id="unitExtention0" class="form-control" name="unitExtention0">

    </div>

    <div id="unitSaleValue" class="col-1">
      <input type="text" id="unitSaleValue0" class="form-control" name="unitSaleValue0">

    </div>

    <div id="estSalesValue" class="col-1">
      <input type="text" id="estSalesValue0" class="form-control" name="estSalesValue0">
    </div>

    <button onclick="addRows()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add a Product</button>
    <button onclick="RemoveRows()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Remove Row</button>
    <button onclick="checkData()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Check Data</button>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

var_dump($_REQUEST)

?>
```

UPDATE:

The code has been changed to use a php array by adding square brackets into the name which produces the following html:

```
<input type="text" id="partNum0" class="form-control" name="partNum[]">
<input type="text" id="partNum1" name="partNum[]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="partNum2" name="partNum[]" class="form-control">
```

Comment: You made this a lot harder on yourself than you needed to. Instead of appending a number to the end of your form input, e.g `partNum0`, you could use square brackets instead. e.g `partNum[]`, and the PHP script will read them as an array. As for your direct problem, I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code in that regard, but I also can't see the HTML that your javascript is generating.

Comment: I'm not seeing `platform` in your HTML, so not sure where you're appending the inputs. Make sure it's within the the form or they won't be included in the form.

Comment: There are a few functions shown here that play not apparent part in the question at hand suggesting there is considerably more HTML / form elements in the actual version. You also are repeating ID attributes `productRow` and it appears that the latter `<div class="row" id="productRow" style="width:95%; margin:auto">` is unclosed

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton could you explain further how the square brackets work? Would I be correct in assuming that if all of the inputs have say partNum[] they are stored in an array somewhere that I can loop through?

Comment: @AmrikAhluwalia Yes. It would be stored in an array like `$_POST['partNum']`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I still have the same issue, I have changed the javascript to give the new inputs the name "partNum[]" however the values in these fields are still not added into the array $_POST["partNum"]. I have added an update to show the HTML for the added fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `name` property of the input and add `[]` at the end, as [GrumpyCrouton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4705262/grumpycrouton) said. PHP parse it as an array, and you can access it as:

```
$partNum = $_POST["partNum"];
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: It turns out the above code did not have any issues with the logic or the way it should work, in the source code in visual studio the indentation of some of the Divs was off causing the browser to have issues in rendering the form correctly hence why the added boxes were not included in the form and their values not POSTED.

As a heads up to anyone with maybe a similar issue, it pays to have your code neat.